# How to solve Memory leaks for following Sqlite code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, memory-leaks, instruments

I am getting memory leaks in Instruments in the following Sqlite Code.

```
NSArray *result = [self executeQuery:sql arguments:argsArray];
```

It calls following method.

```
- (NSArray *)executeQuery:(NSString *)sql arguments:(NSArray *)args {
sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt;

if (![self prepareSql:sql inStatament:(&sqlStmt)])
    return nil;

int i = 0;
int queryParamCount = sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(sqlStmt);
while (i++ < queryParamCount)
    [self bindObject:[args objectAtIndex:(i - 1)] toColumn:i inStatament:sqlStmt];

NSMutableArray *arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int columnCount = sqlite3_column_count(sqlStmt);
while ([self hasData:sqlStmt]) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
        id columnName = [self columnName:sqlStmt columnIndex:i];
        id columnData = [self columnData:sqlStmt columnIndex:i];
        [dictionary setObject:columnData forKey:columnName];
    }
    [arrayList addObject:[dictionary autorelease]];
}

sqlite3_finalize(sqlStmt);

return arrayList;
}
```

How do I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd need to see the code of your `executeQuery` method - it *should* be returning an auto-released result, but perhaps it isn't.

You could try ;

```
NSArray *result = [[self executeQuery:sql arguments:argsArray] autorelease];
```

But I'd be wary of just blindly trying that without actually seeing what `executeQuery` does in detail.

EDIT:

OK, here's your problem;

```
NSMutableArray *arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Either create it as an auto-released array, or finish the method with;

```
return [arrayList autorelease];
```

Comment: Edited my question. for `executeQuery` details.

Comment: See updated answer. Obviously this may have consequences depending on how the rest of your code uses the executeQuery results, but if you are consistent with your memory management you'll be fine.